# $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \textrm{ker}(\nabla g_j)\subset \textrm{ker}(\nabla f)$ implies $\nabla f(p)=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j \nabla g_j(p)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

From linear algebra I know that if $f_1, \ldots, f_n: V\rightarrow \mathbb R$ and $f: V\rightarrow \mathbb R$ are linear functionals on a finite dimensional vector space $V$, then

$$\bigcap_{j=1}^n \textrm{ker}(f_j)\subset \textrm{ker}(f)\iff \exists \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\ \textrm{such that}\ f=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot f_j.\tag{1}$$

Now, let us suppose $f: U\rightarrow \mathbb R$ is a differentiable function on the open set $U\subset \mathbb R^n$ and suppose $g=(g_1, \ldots, g_m): U\rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ is a $C^1$ map. Suppose there is $c\in\mathbb R^m$ and $p\in g^{-1}(\{c\})$ such that

- $\{\nabla g_1(p), \ldots, \nabla g_m (p)\}$ is linearly independent
- $\nabla f(p)=0$.

Using $(1)$ is it possible to show that

$$\nabla f(p)=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot \nabla g_j(p)$$
for some scalars $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\in\mathbb R$?

Of course, the idea would be to show $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \textrm{ker}(\nabla g_j)\subset \textrm{ker}(\nabla f)$. I'm not sure if that is true, but if it is I believe I should apply the implicit function theorem in some way.

**Remark.** Just for sake of curiosity,

$$\bigcap_{j=1}^n \textrm{ker}(f_j)\subset \textrm{ker}(f)\iff \exists \lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\in\mathbb R\ \textrm{such that}\  f=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot f_j$$

is easy to prove. The implication $(\Leftarrow)$ is straightforward. On the other hand, define

$$g:V\rightarrow \mathbb R^n$$

setting

$$g(x)=(f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x))$$

and let $h: \textrm{Im}(g)\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the mapping

$$h(g(x))=f(x).$$
The hypothesis $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \textrm{ker}(f_j)\subset \textrm{ker}(f)$ allows us to conclude $h$ is well defined. Extend $h$ to a linear functional $h: \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$. Then $h$ has the form

$$h(x_1, \ldots, x_n)=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot x_j,$$
for some scalars $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_n\in\mathbb R$.

Then:

$$f(x)=h(g(x))=h(f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x))=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot f_j(x).$$

Comment: Yes, this is know fact, Rudin's "Functional Analysis"  has it as a lemma and there were a few problems here related to it.

Comment: (a) Is there a typo in the Title? - should be $\ker\nabla f$?

Comment: (b) The hypothesis in the Title doesn't seem to occur in the actual question. Can you clarify.

Comment: At the end you say the idea is to prove that each $\ker\nabla g_j$[you have a typo btw]  is in $\ker \nabla f$. I think not, you want to prove that the intersection of the $\ker\nabla g_j$ is in $\ker\nabla f$.

Comment: This is actually a general lemma true for any vector space. You can consult any decent functional analysis textbook. Usually this lemma is proved within the context of weak and weak* topology.

Comment: I agree as to the equivalence $\bigcap_{j=1}^n \textrm{ker}(f_j)\subset \textrm{ker}(f)\iff f=\sum_{j=1}^n \lambda_j\cdot f_j$. Indeed, it is easy to prove that. My actual problem concers the application.